# Selenium IDE: Export to Python when using brackets '(' & ')' in xpaths

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-ide

I have XPath statements in Selenium IDE that don't seem possible to export to Python due to the usage of brackets - any ideas for what to do to get around this to complete the export to Python?

Its statements like: (//td[@role='presentation'])[3]

- The XPath statements seem sound from a syntax perspective since they work both when I play the script in selenium and when I search for the element in the browser with the path.
- When I removed all XPath statements with brackets the export to Python worked.
- I can't use the element IDs because these are dynamically defined and change every other execution

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no problems with brackets in XPath... Can you share more details? At least your Python code

Comment: There is no Python code because the export to Python isn't working. The XPath's are fine in Selenium and I presume in Python (about to test) but the export doesn't seem to recognize it. It can be replicated by trying to convert "click" with the target as any XPath starting with a bracket like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

`(//td[@role='presentation'])[3]` expression can be enclosed with `"`, as following:

```py
"(//td[@role='presentation'])[3]"
```